# Schengen visa application by an Indian studying in the UK

Tags: visas, schengen, uk

I'm leaving for London in 15 days from now for my higher studies. I plan to go to Spain on Sep 23rd. For Schengen Visa, I was wondering under the "financial documents required" section, they want us to show 3 months current account balance. Since I haven't gotten there yet, I don't have an account there.
Could I maybe show my Indian account or do they specifically require UK accounts?

Comment: Where will you be applying for the visa, in India or in London?

Comment: Even if you were there I highly doubt they will let you stay 3 months without documentation so you can accrue current balance.

Comment: I'll be applying from London. No I'm not staying for 3 months! It's just a 4 day trip.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it'll be ok to show your Indian account with your name and the amount in Euro. But if you want to be absolutely sure you can buy traveller cheque for 4 days. They said it has to be minimum of 60 Euros per day (http://www.france.embassy-visa.com/schengen-visa-appointment-requirements). So 240 Euros. But you can buy a cheque for 300 Euros to be absolutely sure then you can exchange it back once the visa has been granted. My friend has done that without any problem.